# A way to initialize variable in beforeEach and use it further - Mocha

Tags: javascript, cypress, mocha.js

I am using Mocha, Typescript and Cypress to write tests.
This is visualization of what I am trying to achieve (so far unsuccessfully :():

```
// this is in example-spec.ts file
context('Sharing variable test', function() {
  let ctx: string;

  beforeEach(function() {
    ctx = 'Value given in beforeEach';
  });

  console.log(ctx); // prints undefined
  consumeCtx(ctx);
});

// this is in separate example-template.ts file
export function consumeCtx(ctx: string) {
    console.log(ctx); // this is undefined
    // use ctx here
    describe('Testing my stuff', function () {
        it('should do something', function () {
          // use ctx here  
          cy.log('This is a test');
        });
      });
}
```

I would like I could somehow fill the ctx data in beforeEach and then use it after that through calling a function which accepts ctx as parameter.
The idea is to have 2 different spec files (e.g. `example1-spec.ts` and `example2-spec.ts`) which can be run separately.
But they still share the same test logic defined in `example-template.ts` file.
And the test data `ctx` specific to each spec file is provided in the spec file and then just passed to the common test logic in template file.
Is there a way to achieve this in the set up that I have created?
Is my approach completely wrong? How would you do it better?
Thanks!

[EDIT]
This is how I reorganized it based on the answers:

In each spec file there is mocha structure.

```
context('Voucher tests', function () {
    let ctx: string;

    beforeEach(function () {
        ctx = 'Value given in beforeEach';
        cy.wrap(ctx).as('ctx');
    });

    describe('Logged in user', function () {
        it('valid voucher ', function () {
            cy.get<string>('@ctx').then((ctx) => {
                console.log(ctx); // should print the value of ctx now
                validCtxTest(ctx);
            });
        });

        it('invalid voucher ', function () {
            cy.get<string>('@ctx').then((ctx) => {
                console.log(ctx); // should print the value of ctx now
                invalidCtxTest(ctx);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And in separate template file I have the shared logic.

```
export function validCtxTest(ctx: string) {
  cy.log('Logic for valid test', ctx);
}

export function invalidCtxTest(ctx: string) {
  cy.log('Logic for invalid test', ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learnt this the hard way. But you need to wrap ctx, provide an alias, and then call that alias to be passed to your function.
I am not a type script person, but hope this helps.
[Edit: adding a working script and result]

```
context("blah",()=> {
    let ctx
    beforeEach( function()  {
        const uuid = () => Cypress._.random(0, 1e3)
        const id = uuid()
        ctx=`some random number ${id}`
        cy.wrap(ctx).as('ctx')
        
    })
    describe("Spec", () => {
        
        it("Test1", function()  {
            cy.get('@ctx').then(ctx=> {
                console.log(ctx)
            })
            
        })
    
        it("Test2", function()  {
            cy.get('@ctx').then(ctx=> {
                console.log(ctx)
            })
        })
    })
})
```

[image]

Also, if you are not planning to have multiple test in a spec file, or pass different value of ctx for each test under 1 spec file, then just ignore the Before hook. You can declare a variable inside your test and then wrap it up and call it anywhere you want in that test. For the next test, do the same.
Its the same approach i have used in my project. fixtures help a lot in defining and passing test data, rather than variables.

Comment: It says "Cannot call cy.get() outside a running test." And I cannot wrap it into a test like 'it' block since in my consumeCtx() method I have describe blocks ... How to resolve this? :/

Comment: I reorganized my stuff so that in the template I have multiple functions containing logic for each of it blocks (tests) and in the spec file I have the structure of mocha tests with context, describe and its. That's the best I can think of. Please let me know if you have better idea. :) Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my answer to illustrate what I have done. Please let me know what you think about it. I like this approach better then the previous answer because with using this there is no intellisense available (you loose the type information)

Comment: @mismas Edit the answer with a working script and result.

Answer (score 4):

You have a mixture of synchronous and asynchronous code. The calls are not in the order you might expect from the test.

`consumeCtx` receives the initial value of `ctx` because it runs before the beforeEach().

To get the value of ctx inside the function use an alias and reference from `this`.

**Test**

```js
import { consumeCtx } from '../support/consumeCtx'

context('Sharing variable test', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    const ctx = 'Value given in beforeEach';
    cy.wrap(ctx).as('ctx')
  });

  consumeCtx();
});
```

**Function**

```js
export function consumeCtx() {
  describe('Testing my stuff', function () {
    it('should do something', function () {
      cy.log('This is a test: ', this.ctx);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why is tis.ctx still undefined when using directly in the body of consumeCtx() method (outside describe or even in the describe block but outside it block). I would like it to be available everywhere ...? :D